# How to get a record with all data associated with it using Python?

Tags: python

I need a bit of direction

I am looking for a way to acquire all the data associated with a client/lead/record inside Salesforce.
I have looked all over the place, and most tutorials only talk about using API's to create new records etc.

I only need to get a lead and acquire all of their info such as: income, address etc.
even if it returns a dictionary, or even perhaps a csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [sObject Get Field Values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_get_field_values.htm) REST API endpoint. Note that

> If you don’t use the fields parameter, the request retrieves all standard and custom fields from the record. These retrieved fields are the same as the fields returned by an SObject Describe request for the object. Fields that are inaccessible to you by field-level security are not returned in the response body.

The most common API library for Salesforce is [`simple-salesforce`](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/). The syntax in that library is given in its documentation (linked):

> To get a dictionary with all the information regarding that record, use:

```python
contact = sf.Contact.get('003e0000003GuNXAA0')
```

Lead can be substituted for Contact in this example.

If you want to extract records at significant volume, you may need to look at a different API, such as sObject Collections, Query, or Bulk API, but this is the appropriate usage for one record or for small numbers of records.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for giving me this lead (pun intended). I shall look into this and mark this answer once I've found what I'm looking for. cheers